# laravel auth for commands and tasks

Tags: laravel

I have a design issue in my Laravel 5.6 app I could do with some guidance on. I need to create a custom command to be able to run a scheduled task from. 
The command will retrieve some sensitive data, and store it.

Currently, the controller that retrieves and stores the data requires auth to invoke it from web-based calls. I don't know of a way to pass auth if I call a custom command. If I call the command, which calls the route for the controller currently a login form is returned on the CLI. Expected! Due to the auth middleware for the route.

I see my options as;

1. Create a new Controller for CLI commands, with no auth. Same functionality as an existing controller, but an assumption is Scheduled Tasks are secure inherently in the confines of the OS and app. Don't like it.
2. Find a way to pass auth from the Scheduled task to the command to the route. Not sure if this can be done. Maybe a little unreliable.
3. Don't call a command from the scheduled task and call a route or controller directly.

Apologies if this is an inappropriate question for here, But am badly stuck on this design issue. Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: Usually to execute any artisan command you need to provide credentials to log on your server and that should be enough.

Comment: agree, should be secure enough. Feel like there is another best practice I am missing or capability with in Laravel to support this scenario. I have searched. I may need to split my controller logic that if the request is web based to ask for auth and it it is artisan sourced, no auth..

Comment: You should separate business logic from presentation logic. If it's something that can be done regardless of context then it probably is business logic and should not be coupled with controllers or middleware.

Comment: agreed, agreed... thanks. Solution is coming after a night away from it :)